# Apache Pig - ERROR 2229: Couldn't find matching uid -1 for project

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera-cdh

I've got the following exception when running a Pig script.

> ERROR 2229: Couldn't find matching uid -1 for project (Name: Project
>   Type: bytearray Uid: -1 Input: 0 Column: 12)

```
org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 2000: Error processing rule ColumnMapKeyPrune. Try -t ColumnMapKeyPrune
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.optimizer.PlanOptimizer.optimize(PlanOptimizer.java:122)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.compile(HExecutionEngine.java:274)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.compilePp(PigServer.java:1324)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1249)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1241)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:335)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:137)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:604)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 2229: Couldn't find matching uid -1 for project (Name: Project Type: bytearray Uid: -1 Input: 0 Column: 12)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.ProjectionPatcher$ProjectionRewriter.visit(ProjectionPatcher.java:91)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.expression.ProjectExpression.accept(ProjectExpression.java:207)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(DepthFirstWalker.java:64)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.walk(DepthFirstWalker.java:53)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.AllExpressionVisitor.visitAll(AllExpressionVisitor.java:72)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.AllExpressionVisitor.visit(AllExpressionVisitor.java:95)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOJoin.accept(LOJoin.java:174)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DependencyOrderWalker.walk(DependencyOrderWalker.java:75)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.ProjectionPatcher.transformed(ProjectionPatcher.java:48)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.optimizer.PlanOptimizer.optimize(PlanOptimizer.java:113)
    ... 16 more
```

What could be the reason? I've looked at the expanded and substituted version of the script and I don't see anything wrong from a syntax point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bug in Pig Optimizer in version 0.11.1 (CDH 4.3). It seems to be related to the attempt at optimizing the following simplified script

```
LOAD A  -- Primary Driver Table
LOAD B
LOAD C
J1 = JOIN A LEFT, B
J2 = JOIN J2 LEFT, C
LOAD D
J3 = JOIN J2, D -- Inner Join
```

Ideally if A was joined with D earlier, then the data flowing through joins J1 AND J2 could reduce and therefore speed up things.

I guess this optimization attempt is failing.

One way to do away with this bug is to identify how you can "promote" join J3 (inner join) to happen earlier in your script.